# How to handle an empty numeric cell in POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Is there any particular reason POI creates a numeric cell when in fact, it's actually empty? What happens is that by the time I get to that cell I obviously get an runtime error as I can't get the string value (it's a numeric cell, after all) and I can't get the numeric value either (can't get a number from an empty string) so my 2 questions would be:

1. How does POI got there?
2. Is there any way I can handle this scenario without having to explicitly go to my excel file?

UPDATE I:
After reading / parsing my excel file, POI generates the following XML for this particular cell:

```
  <x:c r="AA2" t="n">
      <x:v/>
  </x:c>
```

My method is something like this:

```
    final FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("PATH/TO/FILE.xml"));
    final XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
    final XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("SHEET_NAME");

    final int columnCount = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
    for (int rowNumber = 0; rowNumber <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); rowNumber++)
    {
        final XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(rowNumber);
        for (int column = 0; column < columnCount; column++)
        {
            // By now my cell would throw an exception if I attempt cell.getStringCellValue() or cell.getNumericCellValue() as cell.getCellType() returns "0" / NUMERIC
            final XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(column);
            ...
        }
    }
```

I was thinking about adding an additional validation to determine whether the cell is empty by using the getRawValue() method, but not sure if there's a better way to handle this as it was obviously wrongly parsed.

UPDATE II
I've been able to reproduce this scenario by doing adding this as part of a unit test (I still don't understand why POI would fall into this scenario though):

```
    final XLSXSheetConverterImpl xlsxSheetConverter = new XLSXSheetConverterImpl();
    xlsxSheetConverter.setSheetName(SHEET_NAME);
    xlsxSheetConverter.setFilePrefix(FILE_PREFIX);

    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    final XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(SHEET_NAME);

    final XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
    XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(0);
    final CTCellImpl ctCell = (CTCellImpl) cell.getCTCell();
    ctCell.setT(STCellType.N);
    ctCell.setV("");
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post the code (as an [mcve]) that is causing you this problem and highlight where the problem is. Without knowing what you're doing it's not possible to answer your question.

Comment: Hi @erwin-bolwidt, example added

Comment: Can't reproduce - when I create a new Excel file with POI, create a new row and a new cell, then the cell type is "3" - "BLANK". You haven't mentioned what the input `"PATH/TO/FILE.xml"` looks like - it may be that your cell was numeric without value in the input already.

Comment: It's a manually created excel file (created by someone else) and there was no specific formatting set for any cell, just the default, which for most empty cells is good! as POI considers them text cells, like this:

  <x:c r="Z2" t="inlineStr">
    <x:is>
      <x:t xml:space="preserve"/>
    </x:is>
  </x:c>

Comment: Hi @erwin-bolwidt, unit test to reproduce behavior added

Comment: @julioarmandof A cell of type `inlineStr` is a text cell not a number cell, the clue is in the `Str` (string) at the end of the type!

Comment: Hi @gagravarr, That cell is being parsed fine, the problem would be with cell "AA2" which is empty but has type `n` :/

Comment: What `apache poi` version are you using? And why not the latest stable version 3.17? Because this version should properly handling empty `v` in numeric cells. See [XSSFCell.getNumericCellValue](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_3_17_FINAL/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCell.java?view=markup#l273).

Comment: Hi @axel-richter, you are right!!! I found the exact same bug and updating the POI version works!

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in older POI versions, see: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56702

It's been fixed since 3.11 version

Thank you all for your help!!